# Obligatorio while: Programa que pida dos numeros, muestre los valores entre los dos en orden descendente

Tags: python, python-3.x, while

Tal y como indico en el titulo, obligatoriamente usando while tengo que hacer un programa que me pida dos numeros x y z, imprima todos los numeros entre x y z y los ordene descendente. Se hacer el descendente pero no hacer que pare segun el valor inferior. Os dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora. Gracias de antemano comunidad.

## Write a program that reads two numbers x and y,

## and prints all numbers between x and y (or between y and x), in decreasing order.

```
n1=int(input("num"))
n2=int(input("num"))

i=0
while i < n1:
    n1=n1-1
    print (n1)
```

Comment: Sí `n1` es 10 y `n2` 5, el output deberìa ser `10,9,8,7,6` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bye: -xtog

espero que te sea de ayuda. 
Este algoritmo te permite ingresar dos números indistintamente si el primero es mayor  o viceversa, va ha imprimir en forma descendente los números que hay en el rango entre numero 1 y "numero 2":

Pero si deseas que según sea, el orden en el que se ingrese los números, se imprima el conteo en forma descendente entre el rango. Te adjuntare un segundo algoritmo.

primer algoritmo
**For example:**

```
n1=int(input("numero 1 : "))
n2=int(input("numero 2 : "))
i=n1+1
while i < n2 :         #uso de while como condición
     print(i)
     i+= 1
 else:
     x=n1-1
     while x > n2:     #uso de while como condición
     print(x)
     x+=-1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

segundo algoritmo:

**For example:**

```
n1=int(input("numero 1 : ")) 
n2=int(input("numero 2 : ")) 

x=[n1,n2]
x.sort()
#print(x)         #si deseas imprimir tus dos números
i=x[1]-1
while i > x[0]:   #uso de while como condición
    print(i)
    i+=-1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Sí entendí bien, y sí estas obligado a usar `while` y no puedes usar `break` para romper el bucle, puedes simplemente decirle que imprima `n1` siempre y cuando `n1` sea distinto de `n2`.

```
n1=int(input())
n2=int(input())

while n1 != n2:

    print(n1)
    n1-=1
```

Comment: Esto solamente funcionará si n1>n2

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre darle la solución usando python3.8.

```py
n1 = int(input("Introduzce numero 1: "))
n2 = int(input("Introduzce numero 2: "))
i = max(n1, n2) + 1
while (i := i - 1) > min(n1, n2):
    print(i)
```

Donde `max(n1, n2)` saca el numero mayor entre n1 y n2

Usamos while con el operador morsa `(i := i -1) > min(n1, n2)` para asignarle el valor maximo - 1 y compararlo al mismo tiempo con el minimo de n1 y n2.

Respuesta.-

```sh
Introduzce numero 1: 10
Introduzce numero 2: 5
10
9
8
7
6
```

Con esta solución no importa quien es el mayor imprimirá correctamente.

Espero te guste la solución saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esta solución funciona tanto para `n1>n2` como para `n2>n1` ordenándolos de forma descendente y utilizando únicamente `while`:

```
n1=int(input("num"))
n2=int(input("num"))

while n1 > n2 + 1:
    n1 -= 1
    print(n1)

while n2 > n1 + 1:
    n2 -= 1
    print(n2)
```